# Expected ')' to match '(' from line 0 and instead saw 'text'

Tags: javascript

I am getting the following error: Expected ')' to match '(' from line 0 and instead saw 'text'.

Can someone help me? Thank you.

CODE:

```
("<script type="text/javascript" data-rocketoptimized="false" data-cfasync="false" id="LibJquery" src="http://example.com/script.js?dev="+Math["floor"](Math["random"]()*100)+""></script>");
```

Comment: Try replacing your outer " by apostrophes ' so they don't break with the inner "

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that javascript recognize strings:

```
("<script type="text/javascript" data-rocketoptimized="false"....
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    string                            string
```

To solve problem replace the `"` by `'`

```
("<script type='text/javascript' data-rocketoptimized='false' data-cfasync='false' id='LibJquery' src='http://example.com/script.js?dev='+Math['floor'](Math['random']()*100)+''></script>")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
("<script type='text/javascript' data-rocketoptimized='false' data-cfasync='false' id='LibJquery' src='http://example.com/script.js?dev='+Math['floor'](Math['random']()*100)+''></script>")
```

You need to replace all double quotes to single , " to ', except first and last.

It will work !!